# Sort maps by value in the specified order of key's priority

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stdmap

I have three maps of integer

```
std::map<string,int> map1;

map1["ymax"]=10;
map1["ymin"]=16;
map1["xval"]=10;

std::map<string,int> map2;

map2["ymax"]=16;
map2["ymin"]=20;
map2["xval"]=28;

std::map<string,int> map3;

map3["ymax"]=16;
map3["ymin"]=20;
map3["xval"]=10;
```

and a map contain this maps

```
std::map<string,std::map<string,int>> almap;

allmap["map1"]=map1;
allmap["map2"]=map2;
allmap["map3"]=map3;
```

I want to sort the last map as a key `ymin` in the inner map, but if remain equal maps in big map I want to sort as a key `xval` then as key `ymax`, same idea

The right sort to `allmap >> map1,map3,map2`

Comment: `if remain equal maps` if what equal maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create vector of all the maps and sort them by `tie`ing their keys *in the order of key's specified priority*:

```
vector<map<string,int>> v{map1, map2, map3};

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](std::map<string,int> &lhs, std::map<string,int> &rhs){
                                 return tie(lhs["ymax"], lhs["ymin"], lhs["xval"]) < 
                                        tie(rhs["ymax"], rhs["ymin"], rhs["xval"]);}
          );
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/enBvNG)

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of education...

`std::map` requires that the key in the key/value pair is invariant. It also requires that the key fully describes the ordering.

In the case of `allmap`, the key provided is a `std::string`, which is all the map has to go on - even with a complex custom comparison function.

In order to allow any kind of sorting, we would need to roll both the outer name and the maps they represent into one key object, and sort on that.

This starts to argue for either using a set of objects (since there is now no associated data) or keeping a separate, sorted index of keys, sorted by our custom predicate.

Here is the latter:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

struct by_keys
{
  template<class...Keys>
  by_keys(std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>> const& allmap, Keys&&...keys) 
    : keys_ { std::forward<Keys>(keys)... }
  , allmap_(allmap)
  {
  }

  bool operator()(const std::string& ls, const std::string& rs) const
  {
    auto& l = allmap_.find(ls)->second; 
    auto& r = allmap_.find(rs)->second; 
    for (auto& key : keys_)
    {
      auto const& il = l.find(key);
      auto const& ir = r.find(key);
      if (il == std::end(l) && ir == std::end(r)) return false;
      if (il == std::end(l) && ir != std::end(r)) return true;
      if (il != std::end(l) && ir == std::end(r)) return false;
      if (*il < *ir) return true;
      if (*ir < *il) return false;
    }
    return false;
  }

  std::vector<std::string> keys_;
  std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>> const& allmap_;
};

int main()
{
std::map<std::string,int> map1;

 map1["ymax"]=10;
 map1["ymin"]=16;
 map1["xval"]=10;

std::map<std::string,int> map2;

 map2["ymax"]=16;
 map2["ymin"]=20;
 map2["xval"]=28;

std::map<std::string,int> map3;

map3["ymax"]=16;
map3["ymin"]=20;
map3["xval"]=10;

std::map<std::string,std::map<std::string,int>> allmap;

allmap["map1"]=map1;
allmap["map2"]=map2;
allmap["map3"]=map3; 

  // ok, now lets make an index into this map

  std::vector<std::string> sorted_keys;
  for (auto& entry : allmap) { sorted_keys.push_back(entry.first); }
  std::sort(std::begin(sorted_keys), std::end(sorted_keys), 
            by_keys(allmap, "ymin", "xval", "ymax"));

  // sorted_keys should now contain the names "map1", "map3", "map2" 
}
```